# JavaScript: Value assignment to undefined

Tags: javascript

### Case 1

Say I have:

```
a = {}
a.x         // would return "undefined"
```

However I could have

```
b = a.x
```

And the console would only return an `undefined`.

### Case 2

However, if I have:

```
a           // would throw an error saying "ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

And I can't have

```
b = a       // console throws tantrum insisting "ReferenceError: a is not defined"
```

### Question

What's the difference? Both are `undefined` after all. Why doesn't the first one throw an error?

Comment: Because property access is different from referencing a variable in the scope. To check for existence first you'd do `if (typeof a != 'undefined')`, but this is rare.

Comment: An undeclared variable is not the same as an undefined value.

Comment: Both of these comments are true.  In the end, the interpreter is just trying to help by pointing out what's broken.  But your code is equally broken either way.

Comment: @p.s.w.g so "undefined" properties of an object is `undefined` by default. Why not `undeclared` by default?

Comment: @Lucia—"undefined" properties of an object are "not defined", i.e. they don't exist. However, when attempting to access a non–existent property, the value *undefined* is returned. In contrast, when attempting to access a varaible that is not defined, a reference error is thrown. You have discovered the difference between property resolution on objects which proceeds along the `[[Prototype]]` chain and variable resolution on a [*LexicalEnvironment*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3), which proceeds along a scope chain.

Answer (score 0):

So to make things clearer for myself:

```
╭────────────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────────────╮
| Resolution         | Property Resolution    | Variable Resolution   |
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
| Subjective         | Objects                | LexicalEnvironment    |
|────────────────────|────────────────────────|───────────────────────|
| Rule of Procession | Follow Prototype Chain | Follow Scope Chain    |
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Thanks to @RobG. Quote from the helpful [link](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) he provided:

> There are two kinds of Environment Record values used in this specification: declarative environment records and object environment records. Declarative environment records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript language syntactic elements such as FunctionDeclarations, VariableDeclarations, and Catch clauses that directly associate identifier bindings with ECMAScript language values. Object environment records are used to define the effect of ECMAScript elements such as Program and WithStatement that associate identifier bindings with the properties of some object.